# How to do online refund using REST

Tags: magento2, rest-api, refund

Accoring to Magento documentation, endpoint for online refund is:
POST /V1/invoice/<invoice_ID>/refund

So to my understanding, the following call should make an online refund:

```
    curl --location  -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --request POST 'https://example.com/rest/default/V1/invoice/168/refund' \
--data-raw '{
    "items": [
        {
            "order_item_id": 241,
            "qty": 1
        }

    ],
    "notify": true,
    "arguments": {
        "shipping_amount": 6.90,
        "adjustment_positive": 0,
        "adjustment_negative": 1,
        "extension_attributes": {}
    }
}'
```

However, when I check the order, it says "We refunded 12,80 € offline."

[image: offline refund]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `"isOnline": true`, before `"notify": true,`It will create online refund.

Comment: Works! Thanks Amit.